# How to read redirected url parameters from Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync

Tags: single-page-application, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-dialog-api

I am stuck on how to read url parameters/token from redirected page url in Outlook web-addin. I am using DialogAPI to pop up my azure app sign-in/consent page and then trying to read tokens from redirected page.

I can see that token are passed but I couldn't figure out how to read token from url?

```
function GetToken(url)
{
_dlg = Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 40, width: 40 }, function (result) {
                _dlg = result.value;
                _dlg.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
                Office.context.ui.messageParent(somevalue);
            });

}
```

Besides that the processMessage call back never gets triggered, wondering why?

Guys any feedback would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync must be called from the host page and Office.context.ui.messageParent must be called from the Dialog box.

This should be on the host page :

```
var dialog;    
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url,
    {height: 40, width: 40}, function (result) {
         dialog = result.value;
             dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, 
                 function(somevalue){ 
                     console.log(somevalue);});
    });
```

This should be on the Dialog Box :

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(somevalue);
    }
}
```

in your manifest,  must have all the domains being accessed with "https".

1. The URL uses the HTTPS protocol. This is mandatory for all pages loaded in a dialog box, not just the first page loaded.
2. The dialog box's domain is the same as the domain of the host page, which can be the page in a task pane or the function file of an add-in command. This is required: the page, controller method, or other resource that is passed to the displayDialogAsync method must be in the same domain as the host page.

Please [visit here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for more info.

Comment: I can successfully send message back to parent/task pane. Thanks for your comment. However, I cant figure out how can I read tokens from the dialog window which loads the redirected uri containing it.

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to web development, so it was a basic/easy solution. I created html pages within outlook web add-in as redirect URI that we specify in Azure app to send tokens to. Then using JavaScript, I can parse URL which contains access token.